# Преобразование Curl в Java эквивалент?

Tags: java, curl

Здравствуйте! Может ли кто-нибудь подсказать либо о существовании интерпретатора Curl в Java, либо какой (хотя бы приблизительно) аналог кода на Java будет из этого запроса:

```
 curl -i -X POST --data-urlencode "oauth_consumer_key=ЗНАЧЕНИЕ" --
 data-urlencode "oauth_nonce=значение"  --data-urlencode "oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1" --data-urlencode "oauth_timestamp=значение"  --data-urlencode "oauth_version=1.0" --data-
 urlencode "oauth_token=значение"  --data-urlencode "auth_signature=значение" --data "category=3" --data-urlencode "title=Новое название" --data-urlencode "description=Краткое описание" --data-urlencode "message=Полное описание" --data 
"end2br_desc=1&includehtml_desc=no" http://yoursite.ucoz.ru/uapi/news
```

Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вам нужно думать не об обертке над Curl, а об HTTP-клиенте в принципе. Для Java существует масса реализаций HTTP-клиентов. Один из самых известных - [Apache HttpComponents / HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.post("http://yoursite.ucoz.ru/uapi/news")
        .addParameter("oauth_consumer_key", "ЗНАЧЕНИЕ")
        .addParameter("oauth_nonce", "значение")
        .addParameter("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1")
        .addParameter("oauth_timestamp", "значение")
        .addParameter("oauth_version", "1.0")
        .addParameter("oauth_token", "значение")
        .addParameter("auth_signature", "значение")
        .addParameter("title", "Новое название")
        .addParameter("description", "Краткое описание")
        .addParameter("message", "Полное описание")
        .setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(Arrays.asList(
                new BasicNameValuePair("end2br_desc", "1"),
                new BasicNameValuePair("includehtml_desc", "no")
        ))).build();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Comment: ♦ Спасибо, Вам за помощь!