# Конвертация CURL в URL

Tags: java, curl, url, httpclient, oauth2

Всем привет. как правильно перенести запрос из curl в HttpClient или URL, точнее мне нужно авторизироваться (получить токен)

```
curl trusted-app:secret@localhost:8080/oauth/token -d "grant_type=password&username=user&password=password"
```

Через CUrl - все работет получаю токен в ответе, а через HttpClient получаю в ответе

```
{"timestamp":1518116152990,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Bad credentials","path":"/oauth/token"}
```

Пробовал вот так, как описано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554148/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-curl-%D0%B2-java-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82), но вероятно что то напутал.

```
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpUriRequest request1 = RequestBuilder.get("http://localhost:8080/oauth/token")
                    .addHeader("trusted-app", "secret")
            .setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(Arrays.asList(
                    new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"),
                    new BasicNameValuePair("username", "user"),
                    new BasicNameValuePair("password", "password")
            )))
            .build();
    HttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(request1);
    Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response1.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

Заранее благодарен за ответ!

Comment: Не уверен, но попробуйте так: `"http://trusted-app:secret@localhost:8080/oauth/token"`.

Comment: Тогда попробуйте включить максимально подробное логирование на сервере и посмотреть, чем ваш запрос через curl отличается от вашего запроса из Java. Или, поскольку запрос не туннелируется через SSL, можно попробовать использовать подставной сервер, например старинный http://sockspy.sourceforge.net/sockspy.html

Comment: Похоже что получилось - СПАСИБО! 
Единственное что через POST тк GET
`{"error":"method_not_allowed","error_description":"Request method &#39;GET&#39; not supported"}`

Comment: Тогда опубликуйте ответ на собственный вопрос с работающим кодом, поскольку авторизация oauth на Java может много кому пригодиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильная конвертация запроса CUrl для авторизации oauth

```
curl trusted-app:secret@localhost:8080/oauth/token -d "grant_type=password&username=user&password=password"
```

в HttpClient будет такой

```
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpUriRequest request1 = RequestBuilder.post("http://trusted-app:secret@localhost:8080/oauth/token")
            .setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(Arrays.asList(
                    new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"),
                    new BasicNameValuePair("username", "admin"),
                    new BasicNameValuePair("password", "password")
            )))
            .build();
    HttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(request1);

    String theString = convertStreamToString(response1.getEntity().getContent());
    System.out.println("Auth-response3: " + theString);

    Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), response1.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

Где:

- trust-app - логин
- secret - пароль

см. спецификацию [RFC1738](http://freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1738/7.htm) 
Также важно помнить - поддерживается только POST-запрос

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы делаете запрос через curl, в нем `trusted-app:secret` это не HTTP-заголовок, а логин и пароль см. [RFC1738](http://freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1738/7.htm). Заголовок в curl задается, например, так:

`curl --header "Host: localhost" 127.0.0.1`

То есть, то, что вы делаете на Java, не соответствует тому, что вы делаете c curl.